# How we can store different input fields on same column of table with their values by comma,

Tags: php, html, jquery

I want to store dynamic generated input fields in same column of the table with their individual values seperated by commas but using implode for the same is saving only  data of first input type.
i have given name of input field as an array (skill[]) so that it can store multiple value
Here is my code

```
<html>  
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
function check(skill) {
    const selectedSkils = $(skill).val();
    $('.techInput').each(function(i, v) {
      if (selectedSkils.indexOf($(v).attr('id')) !== -1) {
        $(v).removeClass('hide');
      } else {
        $(v).addClass('hide')
      }
    })
  }
  </script>

  <style>

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.techInput {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
  </style>


</head>
<body>
 <form action="submit1.php" method="post" >
  <select name="skills[]" id="skills" multiple onchange="check(this);">
    <option value="css">css</option>
    <option value="php">php</option>
    <option value="magento">magento</option>
  </select>
  <div id="css" class='hide techInput'>
    <label for="sel1"></label><input type="text" name="skill[]" id="selc1" placeholder='css'>
  </div>
  <div id="php" class='hide techInput'>
    <label for="sel2"></label><input type="text" name="skill[]" placeholder='php' id="selc2">
  </div>
  <div id="magento" class='hide techInput'>
    <label for="sel3"></label><input placeholder='magento' type="text" name="skill[]" id="selc3">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Although select inputs are saving in database 
submit1.php

```
<?php
require 'dbserver.inc.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{  
    $f_skills  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,implode(', ', $_POST['skills'])); 
    $f_skill  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,implode(', ', $_POST['skill']));


$query = "INSERT INTO detail ( `f_Skills`,`f_skill`) VALUES (?,?)";

$stmtt = $conn->prepare($query);//prepared statement method 

$stmtt->bind_param("ss",$f_skills,$f_skill );//binding a parameter to question mark

$stmtt->execute();

//testing purpose
echo("Reached here after executing query");

if($stmtt->affected_rows > 0)
{
echo("success");


$stmtt->close();

}
else
{
echo("fail");
}


}
else
{
    echo("error occur please check");
}
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string`